# Access nested data in component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Given the `parent` component in the following context

1.

```
<parent>
  child
</parent>
```

2. 

```
<parent>
  <child />
</parent>
```

Is there a way to access the nested element from the definition of the `parent` component?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [`slots`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html) in `parent`.

example:

```
<template>
This is the parent with child: <slot />
</template>
```